# .NET Core 2 Web API: [FromBody] nested object was not binded

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, binding, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have that post request in my controller:

```
[HttpPost("subscriptions")]
[Authorize(Policy = Policies.Admin)]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostSubscription([FromBody] PostSubscriptionBindingModel model) { ... }
```

where `PostSubscriptionBindingModel` is:

```
public class PostSubscriptionBindingModel
{
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartsOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Gym Gyms { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int SubscriptionTypeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string UserId { get; set; }

    public PaymentBindingModel Payment { get; set; }

    public class PaymentBindingModel
    {
        [Required]
        public double Amount { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public PaymentType Type { get; internal set; }
        [RequiredArray]
        public InstalmentBindingModel[] Instalments { get; internal set; }

        public class InstalmentBindingModel
        {
            [Required]
            public double Amount { get; internal set; }
            public DateTime? ExpiresOn { get; internal set; }
            [Required]
            public bool IsSetPaid { get; internal set; }
        }
    }
}
```

On `Angular` (v.6) side I've a service with this method:

```
postSubscription(model: IPostSubscription): Observable<ISubscription> {
    return this.http.post<ISubscription>(this.originUrl + '/api/subscriptions', model)
        .catch((reason: any) => this.handleError(reason));
}
```

When I try to post my object to the web api controller, while inside Angular service `postSubscription` method the model is fully initialized, on web api side only the first level of the object has values. The property `Payment` (of nested type `PaymentBindingModel`) is not null but its properties are not initialized, like they are not binded.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT (added an image)**

[image]

**EDIT 2 (added client code post model)**

```
export interface IPostSubscription {
    startsOn: Date;
    expiresOn: Date;
    gyms: Gym;
    subscriptionTypeId: number;
    userId: string;
    payment?: ISubscriptionPayment;
}

export interface ISubscriptionPayment {
    amount: number;
    type: PaymentType;
    instalments: ISubscriptionPaymentInstalment[];
}

export interface ISubscriptionPaymentInstalment {
    amount: number;
    expiresOn?: Date;
    isSetPaid: boolean;
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you add to your post the client side model (`IPostSubscription`) you are using?

Comment: @R. Richards I've added the post model as you requested :)

Comment: Have you tried removing the `internal` accessor from the sets in the embedded classes?

Comment: Oh..I didn't see the `internal` accessor at all. I've just tried to remove it and now all works fine! Thank you! And sorry for that stupid thing :D If you will post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order for model binding to work properly, accessors on the property's `get` and `set` should be the default, which is `public` on public properties. Making the accessor `private`, `internal`, or `protected` will cause the model binding to fail.

Most of the time you will not even get an error; the properties will simply show the default value of the property data type.

The model binder is setting the properties with data from an external source, so they need to be publicly accessible.

Comment: Every once in a while, you find an answer that doesn't just help you out, but saves you _hours_ of time. This was one of those answers. Thank you; you'll have a bonus bounty coming your way tomorrow once I can award it.